# Check file existence in Meteor public directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This Meteor client code fails to return true when checking for the existence of a file which exists in the app/public directory.

When used in the browser console like below, it returns `undefined`
`utility.isFileExist('http://localhost:3000/abc.gif')` or
`utility.isFileExist('http://localhost:3000/public/abc.gif')`

Why and now to fix it? Thanks

```
//client/lib.js

utility = (function() {
  return {
    isFileExist: (url) => {
      $.get(url)
        .done(function() {
          return true;
        }).fail(function() {
          return false;
        })
    }
  }
})();
```

**edit as per comment**
Please see this code

```js
Template.checks.helpers({
  'values': function() {
    let result = [];
    let checks = Session.get('items');
    checks.forEach((item) => {
      let url = item.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');

      $.get(url + '.giiif') //<----- files do not exist
        .done(function() {
          console.log(`exists`); //<----- yet this prints out
        }).fail(function() {
          console.log(`does not exist`); //<--- expected this instead
        });

      result.push({
        label: item,
        image: url
      });
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't escape XHR being async, even if you surround it with more syntactic sugar and (unnecessary) IIFEs. You will need some sort of callback to handle the answer (or use async/await and compile it into ES5).

Comment: @MasterAM Please give an example. Thx

Comment: In your code, you should continue the flow of logic in your `done|fail` (or use an `always` instead) callbacks, if you want to use jQuery (Meteor also has an HTTP package). You will not be able to get the result immediately (or with synchronous syntax) with the ES5.

Comment: @MasterAM I edited the question as per your suggestion. why I get the `done` fired but `fail` does not even though the files do not exist? thx

Comment: Most likely because Meteor responds with code 200 and HTML content to any URL that it is not set to specifically respond to otherwise.

Comment: @MasterAM is there other ways to get this job done?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? This method does not seem very useful.

Comment: @MasterAM I am trying to find out if an image.gif file exists in the public directory before referencing its url in the `src` attribute of meteor client template so that I can place a fixed string in its place and use the latter to hide the location of the image since it does not exist using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's figure out what is wrong:

The `utility` code that you posted does not work because XHR is asynchronous, so you cannot get its value using a synchronous operation, such as assignment, in ES5.

The IIFE surrounding the definition is redundant.
The `isFileExist` method itself does not return anything, and if it did, that would be the jqXHR object for the request, that will not give you the data that you are looking for at call time.

Another issue is that Meteor generally responds with the page's HTML for any URL that is not specifically bound to another response. This means that the request will technically succeed (200 OK response code, just not the response you might have expected), so the `fail` callback will not be called in that case as well.

Using the response `content-type` header could be a reasonable method of figuring out if the result is a file or an HTML document.

You can do something like:

```js
utility = {
  doesFileExist(name, cb) {
    $.get(name).done((data, status, request) => {
      const isHtml = request.getResponseHeader('content-type') === 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
      cb(!isHtml);
    })
  }
};


// call it with file name and a callback
utility.doesFileExist('foo.png', (doesExist) => {
  if (!doesExist) {
    // do something if file does not exist
  }
});
```

which will work standalone, but will not allow you to use it in a template helper as it is. You may be able to use a `ReactiveDict` that will track the request state, but it adds a lot of complexity to the code.

Another downside to it all is that you call the server an extra time for each file you wish to check.

---

## Some alternatives

Every `<img>` tag should have an `alt` attribute. In case the image is missing, the `alt` text is shown, but this is not very aesthetic.

Luckily, the `img` tag has an `error` event triggered in case the image cannot be loaded, so you can use it to hide the image or do something else.

```js
Template.foo.events({
  'error img': function(e) {
    $(e.target).hide(); //or something else
  }
});
```

On a side note, you should know what images exist in the `public` folder, as they are statically copied and served at compile time.

It is important to explain what you want to accomplish in the question, and not just ask "how do I do XY?" (as the first part of the answer is not very useful in your case).